# Magento Category Manufacturer setup

Tags: php, magento, categories

I need a help with Magento Category Manufacturer.

Currently, the Main category is divided into two sub-categories - Manufacturer and Product category.

```
Root category
-Manufacturer
--M1
--M2
--M3
-Category
--Cat1
--Cat2
--Cat3
```

When a product is added, the admin selects the Manufacturer and also the category type.

**What we need is - from the Frontend, when user click on a Manufacturer link, it will 1st show available Categories under that Manufacturer, then when clicked on the Category, it will show the products under that Category by that Manufacturer.**

Currently, when we click on the manufacturer link, it shows all it products.

Answer (score 0):

Some times might be you are some missing configuration or not assign product to specific category.

just go throw below two links to manage product and category

[How to Manage Category](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_category.htm)

[How to Manage Product](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_product.htm)

i hope it will sure help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html

it will list sub-categories on specific category page.